# camel-zookeeper Get and Write in same route

Tags: apache-camel

I have use case something like

from("zookeeper:"+path)
.// do something
.to("zookeeper"+path2) // this should create a child node in a different path

when i run this sample every thing looks like working as there are no errors in the logs, but the node is not created for path2

However if i change this to

from("zookeeper:"+path)
.// do something
.process(
    //get a ProducerTemplate template
     template.sendBody("zookeeper:"+path2);
);

this works as expected and creates the node for path2
What could be the reason?  can the route use the same Zookeeper session to get and write in the same route?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: tried with both 2.14.1 and 2.15.0